# Custom membership provide in Sitefinity

Tags: sitefinity, custom-membershipprovider

I need to develop custom membership provider in Sitefinity Project.
I have to shown my users (from my custom table not Sitefinity's inbuilt table) to Sitefinity Backend of the site.
How to do this?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

Have you taken a look at the Sitefinity documentation: http://www.sitefinity.com/documentation/documentationarticles/creating-a-custom-membership-provider

this has a complete tutorial on building a custom membership provider that uses external data to manage users.

I hope this is helpful!